# C programming: getting content in and out of a different file with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, file, console

I've been working my way through "A book on C" (1998) while using Eclipse with Min GW.
I got through most of the exercises in the book but one thing has me stumped.
You have to write a small program, called try_me, and create a small text file, called infile. After that you have to give the command try_me < infile > outfile.
This should copy the contents of infile to outfile, but nothing happens after I type the command (in the console in Eclipse).
I've run into the same problem before where you had to take information out of a file and use it.
I've made the requested .txt file, put some text in it and made sure the file is in the same directory as my try_me.c.

Can somebody help make the translation between whatever they used in 1998 and Eclipse?

Thanks in advance!

For those interested, this is the program:

```
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
```

Comment: Did you try to run the program in a real shell that knows how to redirect input and output? Most IDEs don't redirect by "<" and ">". Eclipse has an option in its "run configuration", but only for input, IIRC. -- Alternatively, did you try to use a real shell in a terminal view of Eclipse? You might need to add a plugin for this.

Comment: @thebusybee, if you could direct me, I would like to try. 
I'm glad I got Eclipse running most of the time and don't really know my way around it.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not the place for such teaching. There are tons of tutorials on the matter, please use your favorite web search engine. -- You might start by using a shell outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been searching but I didn't know where to start. Searching for the word 'shell' helps indeed. 
Do you think it's okay if I, eventually, answer my own question?
It might help future searchers.

Comment: Sure, that's perfectly okay, and you should even mark it as accepted (later, when you're allowed). Only if you answer just a minute after posting your question, it has a smell. ;-)

Comment: If I might get back to this after almost a year?
I've been studying from different books and on different machines. I got the commands working in UNIX. 
Reading this back, I think that is what you meant when you mentioned "a real shell". Am I correct in this matter?
If so, I don't think it's possible to do this with Eclipse.